# Piping to provide a file as input to a C program

Tags: c++, c, linux, command-line, pipe

I have this set of .gz files and inside each of them is a single text file. This text file needs to be used in a C program. The following code solves this problem somehow where parameters 1 and 2 are integers which I'm receiving as arguments for the C program (argc, argv[]) in `main()`.

gzip -dc xyz.txt.gz | ./program parameter1 parameter2

Can someone explain how the above code works in command line?
How does the text file automatically get passed to the program?
Do I need to write extra code in the C program to receive this text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell connects the stdout of one command directly to the stdin of the other command through a [pipe(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe). Neither program has to do anything out of the ordinary to take advantage of this.

Comment: So, I'll need to use a pipe() function inside the C program to open and use the text file?

Comment: **"Neither program has to do anything out of the ordinary to take advantage of this."**

Comment: Oh okay! Sorry there. Thanks.